# Running Maven commands on the command line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to use Maven to export my project into a JAR file, however I am also trying to export the dependencies as well and I am using the shade plugin, however I am wondering how exactly would I then run it? 
I read I need to run "`mvn shade:shade`", however I don't exactly know where I run this? in the terminal I get `'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
So I don't really know where I am supposed to run this

Comment: The Eclipse maven code is just for use inside Eclipse. You need to install maven separately to get command line support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This solution assumes that your project is configured/imported as a Maven project.

Right-click the project in Eclipse. Select `Run as > Maven build... > Goals`, type  `package` and then click `Run`.

Following best practices, you should not run `shade:shade` from the CLI (which you are actually doing with this approach), but rather bind the shade plugin to the `package` phase.

This [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) will explain how to do that, if you haven't already done it.